# Change php settings based on sub-domain in vHost

Tags: php, virtualhost, settings

I have a VirtualHost which direct many subdomains to the same directory.

- moscow.myapp.com
- paris.myapp.com

All those websites run on the same application. The only thing I need to change from a subdomain to another is the php setting date.timezone.

I am not able to touche the application code. I am looking for a way to do so directly in the vHost.

Is it possible ?
How would you do ?

Thank you very much;

Comment: If you have a VirtualHost entry for each city you can use the [`php_admin_value`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) directive to configure a setting specifically for that virtual host.

Comment: I would prefer to keep one vhost for all sites since the timezone is the only param to change. Is there any kind of variable like $subdomain which could help to include extra settings file ?

Comment: You can touch the application code, then. That way, you don't have to make any new VirtualHost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried and researched a way to set the php_admin_value based on a lookup table or a environment variable (set by `SetEnvIf`) and setting the variable with php_value, but found nothing that would probably suit you (having all configuration in one `VirtualHost`).

As a last resort I could advice you to a devious plan, hiding some code...

With the php configuration directive `auto_prepend_file` you could execute some code before actually starting a script. There you can do a lookup based on the virtual host, or use a variable set by `SetEnvIf`.

Apache VirtualHost config:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host "^sandbox.coolhaven.info$" TZ=Europe/Moscow
SetEnvIfNoCase Host "^sandbox2.coolhaven.info$" TZ=Europe/Paris

php_value auto_prepend_file /var/www/misc/timezone_injector.php
```

/var/www/misc/timezone_injector.php

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set($_ENV["TZ"]);
```

Of course, the `SetEnvIf` statements could be moved to a switch statement in your php code.

Your application developer could suspect something happened before their code because the `timezone_injector.php` will show up in stack traces. But this could be a solution if you have a obfuscated or strict licensed PHP applications you are not able to touch due to non technical reasons.

Comment: I was thinking about injecting  a script before the index.php but I did not know the auto_prepend_file setting. I will try this today. Thank you very much.